# Swift UnsafeMutablePointer get pointer to struct member

Tags: c, swift, pointers

I'm interfacing with a C library from Swift, and I've been able to figure out most of the pointer stuff I would normally be able to do in C. However, I'm not sure how to perform this operation. I have a struct, say

```
struct s {
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Then, I have a Swift `UnsafeMutablePointer<s>`, which is fine. I'm able to access individual fields easily, but what I would like is a pointer to a field. Something akin to the following C code:

```
struct s *ex = ...;
int *ptr = &ex->b;
```

Is there a better way than using `withUnsafePointer` on the member itself? I find the following to be a bit messy:

```
let ex = UnsafeMutablePointer<s>.allocate(...)

withUnsafePointer(to: ex.pointee.a) {
    ...
}
```

I attempted to look for similar questions, but I can't seem to find this exact use case in Swift.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &ex.pointee.a)` since you want a *mutable* pointer? Also, what's "messy" about this?

Comment: The pointer will only be available within the passed block and is invalidated on leaving the block context